# Select up to 3 different fields in a table based on the value in another table?

Tags: mysql

Ive seen plenty of examples but none seem to get me where I need it.
I want to Select 1 field from table A, then Check table B for a value, if that value is true(boolean) then also Select field 2 and 3 from table A to return all 3 fields. So if value from B is false only 1 field is selected from table A, if true, all 3 are selected.

Comment: To make sure we understand, you want three columns returned, but in some cases, column 2 and 3 are NULL correct? What happens if the value you check in TableB does not exist (as opposed to being true or false)?

Comment: Hi, I only want 3 columns returned if TableB column value is true. It will always be true or false(0 or 1). If its false just 1 column in TableA

Comment: You can't return a different schema in a single query. The SQL language isn't designed to handle that scenario. You either need one query with all three columns and another to determine if you need column 2 and 3 or you need two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Field1
    , Case
        When Exists (
                    Select 1
                    From TableB
                    Where SomeField = 1
                        And ...
                    ) Then TableA.Field2
        Else Null
        End As Field2
    , Case
        When Exists (
                    Select 1
                    From TableB
                    Where SomeField = 1
                        And ...
                    ) Then TableA.Field3
        Else Null
        End As Field3
From TableA
```

---

**Update**

The above solution works fine if what you want is a three column result every time even if some of those columns are null. However, if what you want is a different number of columns returned based on the query, then this is something that cannot be done in a single query. The SQL language was not geared to handle on-the-fly schema generation. My suggestion would first be to evaluate why you want a different number of columns from the same query and determine if you cannot simply handle the scenario in your middle-tier where column 2 or 3 is NULL. That is by far the simplest solution and could be done in a single query:

```
Select TableA.Field1, TableA.Field2, TableA.Field3
    ,   (
        Select TableB.SomeBooleanColumn
        From TableB
        ) As TableBValue
From TableA
```

Your middle-tier code would then determine whether to do something with Field2 and Field3.

That said, if you insist on having two column structures, you need two queries:

```
Select TableA.Field1
From TableA
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From TableB
                Where TableB.SomeColumn = 0
                )
```

After calling this query, you would evaluate whether you got a row. If you got no rows, you could then call this query:

```
Select TableA.Field1, TableA.Field2, TableA.Field3 
From TableA 
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From TableB
                Where TableB.SomeColumn = 1
                )
```

What hasn't be stated in the OP is the scenario where there is no row in TableB.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it appears that I will have to use two queries. How would i combine those two? The row will always be there as stated above. It is part of the table structure. It will be either 0 or 1. Its part of the members settings. So if they allow more info, then get fields 2 and 3 from table A. Other wise just field 1. I use PHP but the way I have it seems easier to do it with the mysql statements.

Comment: @Pjack - I would use the single query example (third query from the bottom), and use PHP to determine whether to return (to the browser) only a single field or multiple depending on the value of TableBValue column.

Comment: I ended up using a single query with some joins and used php to do other stuff. Close to what I needed so I'll accept the answer since it was a bit easier to do and gave me another way to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use case expressions:

```
    select A.field1,
           case B.boolValue when 1 then A.field2 end AS field2,
           case B.boolValue when 1 then A.field3 end AS field3

    from TableA A join TableB B on A.? = B.?
```

I don't know what your A and B tables are linked on so you'll have to fill in the ? marks.  This will return null values for field2 and field3 when B.boolValue is false.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't get that to work. Maybe I was doing something wrong.